# Plot shown by Region does not show the full region

Tags: plotting, regions

Why does the plot produced by the following code not contain the point `{0. 0}`?

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[y <= x/2 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, y}], 
  PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Why does the above not plot a wedge starting at 0, like this:

[image]

As far as I understand my code, I first define a region that follows the inequalities specified by `ImplicitRegion`, and then call `Region` to plot it.

Yet still, I seem to have made a mistake. What is it?

Comment: Using `{{x, 0,1}, {y, 0,1}}` instead of `{x,y}` as the second argument fixes the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `RegionPlot` works better than `Region`.  `Region[DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[..],..]` also works.

Comment: You could also use `RegionPlot`: `RegionPlot[y <= x/2 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> True]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. This "proofs" that it is the visual part that is messing up, and not the calculus part. Should I classify the shown behavior as bug?

Comment: @Sudix I don't think it's a bug.  Numerical routines always suffer from discretization errors.  I don't think `Region` is meant to be robust in the way you're using it. I'd recommend `DiscretizeRegion` as the tool to use. It has options to control the discretization.  `RegionPlot` tries a harder than `Region`, but it's not as robust as `DiscretizeRegion` (or the FEM `ToElementMesh`, which allows even finer control).

Comment: @MichaelE2 But wouldn't one generally let `Region` use its 2D and 3D analogon if possible - or the other way around, code `RegionPlot` as a special instance of `Region`?

Comment: `RegionPlot` is a 2D plotter, and `RegionPlot3D` is a 3D plotter.  `Region` is not a plotter.  What you see is result of the Front End displaying a 2D `Region`: it makes a quick plot of it to show in the notebook, but the result of `Region` is not `Graphics`.  If you want a `Region`, use `Region`. The bad picture does not indicate a bad result. In fact, the result is still accurate.  Compare `Region[..] // InputForm // Short` and `RegionPlot[..] // InputForm // Short` on your region code and my plot.

Comment: For instance, you can use `RegionPlot` on your `Region` and you get accurate graphics.  You can also use `DiscretizeRegion` on it.  That is, if you want to have your `Region[..]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

The discretization made automatically by `Region` is a bit strange, but it does satisfy all the condition you give. Perhaps `Region`'s boundary choice is bad enough that the behavior you complain about should be considered a bug.

However, as things stand, to get what you want you must give `Region` better specifications of the boundary you want. One way to it is

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[y <= x/2 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}}], 
  Axes -> True]
```

Another is

```
Region[
 DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[y <= x/2 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, y}], 
   {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}],
 Axes -> True]
```

Both work-arounds produce

[image: region]

Comment: But ImplicitRegion can be used as I did according to the documentation: ImplicitRegion[cond,$\{x_1,...,x_n\}$]; represents a region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies the conditions cond.

Comment: @Sudix. Valid point. I have edited my answer in way that I hope addresses it.